# Is My Offer Too Low - May Someone Provide An Accurate Salary Calculator?

Tags: salary, job-offer

I was given an offer as an Operations Solutions Developer for the company that I've been interning for the past 1+ years.  I currently have been developing ETL processes  that has had results in saving the company money and providing more time for high value analysis.

I am a double major with B.S. Computer Information Systems and B.S. Supply Chain Management; I graduated Cum Laude and I recently graduated 12/2014.

I was given the offer of $60k/yr and the organization is in the Aerospace and Defense industry.  I did some research on GlassDoor for Solution Developer 1 position salaries in Phx, AZ.  It stated that there was not enough info to provide an average salary for the position.  From what I was looking at there were about 20 salaries for Solution Developer 1 in Phoenix, AZ and manually calculated the average at $70K/yr.

I have 3+ years with IT experience in all realms.  The offer was just put out there and was given a couple weeks to except.  It was never stated that this was "the final and only offer."

Given the information I have provided.  Do you think $60k/yr was a low ball?  Or if you may, can you provide a website that has proven accuracy in calculating a salary given my experience.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "accurate salary calculator" - there is simply what an employer is willing to pay and what you are willing to accept (and, hopefully, a satisfactory compromise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

research it a bit more and ask for something you would be comfortable with. explain the reasons behind asking for more.

if you are asking for something reasonable 2 outcomes are possible: you're going to get it or not.

if you don't ask this will plague you as long as you work there.

Comment: all I can do negotiate I guess; worst case scenario is that they say "no" :)

Comment: be reasonable. explain why you are asking. you'll be fine

Answer (score 3):

You are only 4 months out of school and have only 3ish years of it experience( your post did not state if this was professional experience or not but I am assuming professional) , which makes you pretty green still.

$60k for a junior developer is reasonable , while its not great it's reasonable.

Even though in your role you are saving them a crapload of money you should take note that this is your job to do this, it's not like you are going above and beyond to save them money. Some roles are extremely profitable for companies but this is no reflection of what you should be paid , I can use the example of a internal sales rep, yes he may be answering the phone all day and taking a total amount of orders which brings in double his salary in profit, so he may ask for a raise to reflect this, but he fails to realise that 50% of that profit has to go to warehouse staff, 30% goes to it and management costs, and the remaining 20% is either profit or being saved for a rainy day )

In my experience with aerospace/defence even though it sounds pretty cool those sorts of companies are really the tightest when it comes to paying their employees ( this statement does not apply to contractors though )

It should be noted that no such website as you are requesting exists, based on my experience and skills I know that I can ask anywhere from 130 to 250k per year and get it, but there are a incredible amount of factors which determine the difference between those 2.

Comment: I actually have gone above and beyond; all I can do is negotiate and they can say no I guess.  I just needed to know if it was low.

Comment: Don't forget you need to include vacation, benefits, work environment, management, company reputation, future value of the experience you will gain, etc. There's more to think about than base salary alone. I do agree, that seems a bit low.  Ask if they can do $65k and see what happens. :)

Comment: @user216392 mjulmer makes a good point. If they say no to a salary bump, ask if they could be flexible elsewhere, e.g. vacation days. The raw monetary cost to them for giving you an extra week of vacation ought to be less than $5k per year. Having good benefits is nothing sneeze at. You might feel differently of course, but I'm a lot happier with better benefits even if it means marginally less compensation after tallying the figures.